# How to solve this with correct query in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot-table

Here's a screenshot of the data.

[image]

Here, I want to compare columns (`Sal, TA, DA`) in the basis of two different year (e.g. 2013 and 2014) with order by month...so that my output must be like following...

[image]

Please give me query for this

Comment: Please first show us the query that you already have! We'll be glad to help if you're stuck somewhere - but we're not just going to write the whole code for you.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like

```
select EMP_ID, MONTH,
max( case when Year=2013 then Sal else null end) as Sal_2013, 
max( case when Year=2014 then Sal else null end) as Sal_2014, 
max( case when Year=2013 then TA else null end) as TA_2013, 
max( case when Year=2014 then TA else null end) as TA_2014, 
max( case when Year=2013 then DA else null end) as DA_2013, 
max( case when Year=2014 then DA else null end) as DA_2014
from  table1
group by EMP_ID, MONTH
```

Comment: Thanku for query it is working